# Feathered Headdress from the Islander, female figure

Tags: minifigures, piece-usage

Is there a way to attach the [feathered head dress](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6029b&idColor=1#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D) from the [Islander, Female](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?M=pi066) figure to any other headpiece? (I'm trying to make a Vegas showgirl.)

Comment: It appears to use a bar to connect to other items, so obviously you will need a special hair with clips all over it, and i doubt such thing exists. Perhaps you can look for a different part, or specify where exatly you want to attach it?

Comment: There is [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95326&name=Minifigure,%20Hair%20Female%20Messy%20with%20Swept-up%20Ponytail,%20Side%20Bangs%20and%20Clip&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Hair%5D#T=C) hairpiece with a clip, although it's facing forwards instead of up

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes ignoring a problem yields its own solution - like the [Cabaret Singer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=col385).

[image: Collectible minifig series 21]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using part [15712](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15712&name=Tile,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Open%20O%20Clip&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=C) 'tile 1x1 with C clip'. Just place that on top of the minifig head and then place the white part in the clip.

You could have used a bar with clip but most if not all minifig heads don't have a fully hollow stud, only solid, or semi-hollow, so the bar would not be able to go all the way down and even if it did the minifigs torso would still probably be in the way.